# Maven generated JAR on windows can't find find main on linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, raspberry-pi

I'm sorry if this problem has already bean solved but i still haven't found solution  ,

I have a jar from a java application created with maven-compiler-plugin .
 This Jar works perfectly on windows and MACOSX . 
And i would like to run it on a  raspberry pi  (so linux) , but when i try , i get this error :

[image]

(so the translation of the error is : Error impossible to find or load the main class sg.Main)

If anyone knows where it could come from , that would be very nice of you :)

Comment: can you add to the question the output of `java -version` on the raspberry?

Comment: I checked , that’s java 8 , the correct one ... but good try !